# How to deploy a large docker image to Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to push this docker image to my PCF environment:

https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/tensorflow-notebook/tags/

The image is 3.9GB when extracted.

When I do:

`cf push jupyter-minimal-notebook --docker-image jupyter/minimal-notebook -m 8GB -k 4G`

I get the error:

> The app is invalid: disk_quota too much disk requested (requested 4096 MB - must be less than 2048 MB)

The default disk space an app gets is 1024mb by default. This is set in `cloud_controller_ng` in the `default_app_disk_in_mb` parameter.

The maximum amount of disk a user can request is 2048mb by default. This is set in `cloud_controller_ng` in the `maximum_app_disk_in_mb` parameter.

I believe the solution is to increase the value for `maximum_app_disk_in_mb` however, after much searching I cannot figure out how to set it.

I have tried the following in the `manifest.yml`:

```
---
applications: 
- name: jupyter-tensorflow-notebook
  docker: 
    image: jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
  cloud_controller_ng:
    maximum_app_disk_in_mb: 4096
  disk_quota: 4G
  memory: 8G
  instances: 1
```

This does not work and returns the same error:

> The app is invalid: disk_quota too much disk requested (requested 4096 MB - must be less than 2048 MB)

UPDATE September 3rd 2019:

I didn't give enough background. I've setup a Small Footprint PCF environment on AWS using the AWS Quickstart, so I have full control over the deployment to tweak whatever parameters I'd like. In effect I'm the platform operator. So the question is, given I have the rights to make the changes to `maximum_app_disk_in_mb` how would I go about doing that? I'd like to change the `maximum_app_disk_in_mb` parameter but can't see how to do that without redeploying the entire environment.

To get the manifest that was used in Quickstart I figured that I needed to do the following:

`bosh -e aws -d [my-deployment] manifest`

This from what I understand is the complete manifest. There are a lot of variable parameters in it such as `((cloud-controller-internal-api-user-credentials.password))` etc.

Is there a way to update `maximum_app_disk_in_mb` without redeploying the complete manifest?

If I have to redeploy the complete manifest is the best way to do this by doing:

`bosh -e aws -d [my-deployment] manifest > manifest.yml`

Then editing `maximum_app_disk_in_mb` parameter value in the `manifest.yml` and redeploying? If I do this will it pick up on all the values for parameters that are using variables in the manifest such `((cloud-controller-internal-api-user-credentials.password))`?

When I do:

`bosh -e aws deployments`

There seem to be two deployments, `aws-service-broker-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and `cf-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` (I've replaced the id with x's for anonymity). The former doesn't have any running instances so I guess I don't need to make any changes to that one?

Comment: `Is there a way to update maximum_app_disk_in_mb without redeploying the complete manifest?` -> Yes and no. You could always ssh into Cloud Controller and adjust the configuration file, `monit restart` the cloud controller process and it would apply your change. That won't persist beyond a recreate of your Cloud Controller VM though. To make the change stick, you would need to edit your deployment manifest and `bosh deploy`.

Comment: `If I do this will it pick up on all the values for parameters that are using variables in the manifest such ((cloud-controller-internal-api-user-credentials.password))?` -> You might need to specify the values when you `bosh deploy` or it might pull them from CredHub, depends on how you have things set up. I don't know the AWS quick start so I don't know how it configures things. Sorry.

Comment: You're really asking a completely different question now. You should open a new SO post.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just start by saying that you, as a developer/end user, of Cloud Foundry cannot change settings in Cloud Controller, which is a system level component. Only your operator could do that.

If you could change settings in Cloud Controller, that would void all the limits set by Cloud Controller and your platform operators, as you could just set them as high as you want.

Cloud Controller will set a default disk size, which takes effect if you do not set one, and it will set a maximum disk size, which limits you from consuming too much disk on the foundation and impacting other users.

I don't believe there is a way to fetch the max disk space allowed by Cloud Controller & your platform operator other than just specifying a large disk quota (try `cf push -k 99999G`) and looking at the response.

As you can see from your response, Cloud Controller will tell you in the error message the maximum allowed value. In your case, the most it will allow is 2G.

> The app is invalid: disk_quota too much disk requested (requested 4096 MB - must be less than 2048 MB)

There's nothing you can do to get a disk above 2G, other than write to your platform operator and ask them to increase this value. If this is your company's platform, then that is probably the best option.

If you are using a public provider, then you're probably better looking at other providers. There are several public, certified providers you can use. See the list here -> https://www.cloudfoundry.org/thefoundry/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @DanielMikusa - I didn't give enough background. I've added more details to the post. I have full control over the deployment as I deployed it to AWS using the AWS Quickstart. Hope that helps give more background.